# Why is this an invalid variance?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, covariance

Exact code I'm trying to build:

```
    public interface IMapContainer<out T> where T : MapRoomBase
    {
        String GetName();

        IEnumerable<T> GetRooms();
    }
```

I'm getting this error:
Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'MapLibrary.IMapContainer.GetRooms()'. 'T' is covariant.

I was under the impression that this would be valid since IEnumerable simply returns the items, and none can be added. Why is this not safe + valid?

Comment: I'm sorry, but why `out T`? Do you need that `out`?

Comment: Why is T an out parameter from your Interface?? What are you trying to achieve? from my perspective that looks odd/wrong.

Comment: @Xtian, Andre, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx.

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert yes it does. That's how Julien Lebosquain could give a correct answer.

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert Yes, that does make it different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you're not targeting an old framework version. `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant starting with .NET 4. Your code compiles fine under .NET 4 and fails with the error you mention on .NET 3.5.

Comment: It seems that covariance is not supported in IEnumerable in SL 4. Your answer helped me find that, although I don't understand why this is... http://forums.silverlight.net/t/184882.aspx/1

Comment: Covariance is supported in SL4 just the BCL types like IEnumerable<T> is only made Covariant in SL5 see this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2558592/872395)